# Загрузка сразу всех страниц на Vue при переходе на сайт

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть 3 страницы. Как при первом переходе на одну из них сразу загрузить остальные 2 во Vue? Например, мы впервые открыли сайт и попали на главную страницу и сразу загрузили остальные, и после перехода на другую страницу ничего грузиться не будет, т.к. она уже готова. Использую `router-view`.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше условие "ничего грузиться не будет" - означает отсутствие запросов на сервер? Тогда необходимо использовать Promise и по исполнении первого запроса (для главной страницы) по .then исполнять остальные запросы данных с сервера (они асинхронно будут получены - и тогда вы можете их сохранить в Vuex или, как вариант - в переменных при Composition API Vue 3.
Далее если они уже получены ( не километровые))), можете их использовать для последующих страниц/компонентов.
Все зависит от архитектуры вашего сайта.